# Can you export RB3 songs into RB:Blitz?

Tags: rock-band-3, rock-band-blitz

My Rock Band 1 and Rock Band 2 exports appear in the songs for Rock Band Blitz, and I'd love to play some of the songs in RB3 on Blitz as well. Is there anyway to import the RB3 songs into Blitz?

Answer (score 1):

[No](https://twitter.com/RockBand/status/213012138355200000). Blitz songs work in RB3, though.